# git archive from a remote downloads LFS file pointers only, not actual LFS files

Tags: git, git-lfs

I noticed that 'git archive' supports LFS when archiving from a local repo but not when archiving from a remote. Here are the git commands I used

```
git archive -o latest.zip HEAD
git archive -o latest.zip HEAD --remote=<remote git repo>
```

The first one, which operates on the local repo, works.  The second one does not. Only pointers pointers to the LFS files, instead of the actual LFS files, are included in the archive.  Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The way that Git LFS works is by setting up a smudge/clean filter, usually using a filter process, in the local repository.  Even if a file is specified to use the LFS filter, it won't be effective unless the configuration has the options to enable the filter process.

It's likely that on your local system, you have Git LFS installed and configured, and on the remote system, you don't.  Since the remote system lacks the configuration, the `git archive` process is not invoking the Git LFS binary.

Even if you have the configuration set up properly, you need some way to have the remote side fetch the objects if they're not already stored in the repository.  If they are, the Git LFS binary will use them, but if you're not, you're going to need some way to authenticate to whatever LFS server you're using as part of the process.  That will require functional credentials, accessible to the Git server, that allow it to access the LFS server, which will probably be tricky.

The Git LFS binary is not usually intended for non-interactive use, since it can prompt for credentials, so you may want a custom filter that fetches from the LFS storage more directly.

Comment: bk224, I know the remote system is configured properly for LFS because when I go to the gitlab ui, I can see them marked as LFS.  Also when I do a clone, they are fetched as actual files and not as pointers only.  What I do not understand from your reply is Git LFS binary is not using them when doing a git archive.  How can I verify that that is indeed the case?

Comment: The question is whether the remote repository you've specified with `--remote` has the actual `git-lfs` binary on it and is configured to use it.  If that's a GitLab server, then it almost certainly isn't, because the server (a) doesn't have the binary and (b) isn't configured for authentication with it.  The fact that it shows up in the UI is irrelevant, because that almost certainly doesn't use the binary.